# Convergence of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{nf(n)}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, sequences-and-series

*This problem is taken from Vojtěch Jarník International Mathematical Competition 2010, [Category I, Problem 1](http://vjimc.osu.cz/j20/j20problems1.pdf). <sub><sup>— edit by KennyTM</sup></sub>*

---

On going through this post [Does there exist a bijective $f:\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ such that $\sum f(n)/n^2$ converges?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2120/does-there-exist-an-f-mathbbn-to-mathbbn-such-that-sum-fn-n2-conve) i happened to get the following 2 problems into my mind:

Let $f: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ be a bijection. Then does the series $$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{nf(n)}$$ converge?

Next, consider the series $$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n+f(n)}$$ where $f: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ is a bijection. Clearly by taking $f(n)=n$ we see that the series is divergent. Does there exist a bijection such that the sum above is convergent?

Comment: Clearly, for the second question, if $f(n)$ satisfies $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{f(n)}=0$ ($f(n)$ grows much faster than $n$), the second sum converges.

Comment: J.M. It won't, since $f$ is a bijection, $n/f(n)\ge1$ infinitely often.

Comment: @Robin, mini-tip: when writing a comment to someone (even a commenter) you can prefix the name with an @ and s/he'll get a notice about it---like you about this one.

Comment: @Robin: Hmm, on second thought, you're right. @Mariano: For me, sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hints. For the first series, prove that
$$\sum_{n=1}^N\frac1{nf(n)}\le\sum_{n=1}^N\frac1{n^2}.$$

For the second, what would happen if $f$ were an involution,
and in each pair $(n,f(n))$ one term was much bigger than the other?

Answer (score 3):

A [couple of proofs](http://www.scienzematematiche.it/forum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=2322) in italian.

Comment: The problem comes from the 2010 Vojtěch Jarník International Mathematical Competition ( http://vjimc.osu.cz/ ).

Comment: The link is no longer valid. I wonder if you know an alternative link?

Answer (score 2):

For question $2$, consider any $f(n)$ which is $2^n$ for $n$ which are not powers of $2.$ This lets us divide our sum into two parts, both of which converge.