# Show that the series of $f(n)/n^2$, were $f$ is an injective function, diverges.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, divergent-series

Consider an injective function $f: \Bbb N \rightarrow  \Bbb N$

Show that the series given by:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{f(n)}{n^2}$$

diverges.

I'm really not sure how to use the injectivity hypothesis, so any suggestion or any answer would be well received.

Comment: ^How do we know that holds for all $n$? The function $f$ defined by $f(1) = 2$, $f(2) = 1$, and $f(n) = n$ for $n \ge 3$ does not satisfy $f(n) \ge n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @JimmyK4542  $\sum \dfrac{f(n)}{n^2} \geq \sum \dfrac{n}{n^2}$

Comment: @Aram That requires proof.

Comment: @user192666 I've added a proof here that uses precisely your hypothesis of injectivity: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2120/does-there-exist-a-bijective-f-mathbbn-to-mathbbn-such-that-sum-fn

Answer (score 0):

Hint. Determine how $f$ would need to be selected in order to make the $N$th partial sum as small as possible.