# Existence of a bijective function from the set of natural numbers to itself such that the following condition satisfy

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functions, divergent-series

> Does there exist a bijective function $g:\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{N}$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{g(n)}{n^2}<\infty$

**My approach**

Suppose it does then the sequence $(\frac{g(n)}{n^2})_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ converges to zero.
Then for any $\epsilon>0\ $ we get an $ \ m\in \mathbb{N}$ such that  $ \ 0<\frac{g(n)}{n^2}<\epsilon, \ \forall\ n\geq m $ 
$g(n)<\epsilon n^2, \forall\ n\geq m$
 can't proceed from here...

**more thoughts**
Observations:

1. For g(n)=1 constant function the series is convergent, can't find any more such which for good is bijective
2. Taking the bijective function g(n)=n we get that the series becomes the harmonic series which is divergent. That also won't work

But those gives no conclusion, any idea ?

Comment: This question is duplicated [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2120/691503)

Comment: @Zaragosa Thanks